# Proof of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(x^2)dx=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fresnel-integrals

If I want to prove that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(x^2)dx=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}
\end{equation*}

*First method:*
It is possible to approach it by the method in which we consider a closed curve, then:
Let gamma be one eighth of a circle ($\theta\in[0,\pi/4]$), then
\begin{eqnarray*}
            0 = \int_{\gamma} e^{iz^{2}} dz 
            & = &   \int_{\gamma_{1}} e^{iz^{2}} dz + 
                    \int_{\gamma_{2}} e^{iz^{2}} dz + 
                    \int_{\gamma_{3}} e^{iz^{2}} dz \\
            & = &   \int_{0}^{R} e^{iz^{2}(r)} dz(r) + 
                    \int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{iz^{2}(\theta)} dz(\theta) + 
                    \int_{R}^{0} e^{iz^{2}(r)} dz(r) \\
            & = &   \int_{0}^{R} \cos(x^{2}) + i\sin(x^{2}) dx + 
                    \int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{iz^{2}(\theta)} dz(\theta) + 
                    \int_{R}^{0} e^{iz^{2}(r)} dz(r) \\
        \end{eqnarray*}

Then
\begin{equation*}
            -\int_{0}^{R} \cos(x^{2}) + i\sin(x^{2}) dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{iz^{2}(\theta)} dz(\theta) + \int_{R}^{0} e^{iz^{2}(r)} dz(r)
        \end{equation*}
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
            \int_{R}^{0}\exp\left(iz^{2}(r)\right)dz(r) 
            & = & \int_{R}^{0}\exp\left(i(re^{i\pi/4})^{2}\right)e^{i\pi/4}dr \\
            & = & \int_{R}^{0}\exp\left(ir^{2}e^{i\pi/2}\right) \cdot e^{i\pi/4}dr \\
            & = & -e^{i\pi/4} \int_{0}^{R}\exp\left(ir^{2}e^{i\pi/2}\right)dr \\
            & = & -e^{i\pi/4} \int_{0}^{R}\exp\left(ir^{2}[\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2)]\right)dr \\
            & = & -e^{i\pi/4} \int_{0}^{R}\exp\left(-r^{2}\right)dr \\
        \end{eqnarray*}
and we know that
\begin{eqnarray*}
            \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{0}^{R}\exp\left(-r^{2}\right)dr = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
        \end{eqnarray*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
            \begin{split}
                &
                \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{R}^{0}\exp\left(iz^{2}\right)dz  = -\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right) \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\\
                \Rightarrow
                &
                \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{R}^{0}\exp\left(iz^{2}\right)dz = -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}-i\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}
            \end{split}
        \end{equation*}
And I wish that
$\left|\int_{\gamma_{2}} e^{iz^{2}}dz\right|=|\int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{iz^{2}(\theta)} dz(\theta)|\to 0$ when $R\to\infty$. How can I argue this in detail?

since using this I would have to
\begin{equation*}
            \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{R} \cos(x^{2}) + i\sin(x^{2}) dx = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4} + i\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}
        \end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}
        \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^{2})dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(x^{2})dx = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}
    \end{equation*}
that concludes the desired.

*Second method:*
On the other hand, Also study the possibility of doing this problem using power series. We know that
\begin{equation*}
 \sin(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
 \Rightarrow \sin(z^{2}) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(z^{2})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
        \int_{0}^{r}\sin(x^{2})dx 
        & = &    \int_{0}^{r} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(x^{2})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} dx\\
        & = &    \int_{0}^{r} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!} dx\\
        & = &    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\int_{0}^{r} x^{4n+2} dx\\
        & = &    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\left. \cdot\frac{x^{4n+3}}{4n+3} \right|_{0}^{r}\\
        & = &    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!} \cdot \frac{r^{4n+3}}{4n+3} \\
    \end{eqnarray*}

But I do not know how to reduce or work with this expression, if someone could help me I would be very grateful.

PD: If there is another method, perhaps by Fourier analysis it is also welcome, although my main interest is to exercise with the theory of the complex variable.

Comment: Use the first method since the second  leads to the Fresnel integral.

Comment: I understand, I still cannot conclude using the first method, because I need the arc term to tend to zero when the radius tends to infinity. I can't see how to work that detail.

Comment: See also Desbrow, Darrell,
"On evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax(x-2b)}dx$ by contour integration round a parallelogram."
*Amer. Math. Monthly* **105** (1998), no. 8, 726–731.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral which you mention is $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \exp(i (R cos(\theta) + i R sin(\theta))^2) i R \exp( i \theta) d\theta$$

Taking the modulus of this thing, it is less than $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} R \exp(-R^2 sin(2 \theta)) d \theta = \frac{R}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \exp(-R^2 sin(\theta)) d\theta$$

on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ by concavity of sine, we have $\sin(\theta) \geq \frac{2 \theta}{\pi}$

so $$\frac{R}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \exp(-R^2 sin(\theta)) d\theta \leq \frac{R}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \exp(-R^2 \frac{2 \theta}{\pi}) d \theta =  \frac{\pi(1 - \exp(-R^2))}{4 R}$$ and $$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi(1 - \exp(-R^2))}{4 R} = 0$$ so we get the result you desired.

Comment: To clarify, this is the integral of the arc term you mention.

Comment: Thanks! It would not have occurred to me to use the concavity